# Mount physical folder to SQL Server docker container using WSL2 base

Tags: sql-server, docker, wsl-2

I'm trying to create a container of SQL Server in Docker Desktop based on WSL2 but my container can't start (exited 1 after start). In logs tab show permission denied. Here is the content of the log file.

```
2023-01-02 17:31:56 /opt/mssql/bin/permissions_check.sh: line 4: [: : integer expression expected
2023-01-02 17:31:56 /opt/mssql/bin/permissions_check.sh: line 59: [: : integer expression expected
2023-01-02 17:31:56 SQL Server 2022 will run as non-root by default.
2023-01-02 17:31:56 This container is running as user mssql.
2023-01-02 17:31:56 To learn more visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2099216.
2023-01-02 17:32:59 ** ERROR: [AppLoader] Failed to load LSA: 0xc0070102
2023-01-02 17:32:59 AppLoader: Exiting with status=0xc0070102
2023-01-02 17:32:59 This program has encountered a fatal error and cannot continue running at Mon Jan  2 10:32:59 2023
2023-01-02 17:32:59 The following diagnostic information is available:
2023-01-02 17:32:59 
2023-01-02 17:32:59          Reason: 0x00000006
2023-01-02 17:32:59         Message: Termination of \SystemRoot\system32\AppLoader.exe was due to fatal error 0xC0000001
2023-01-02 17:32:59         Address: 0x3fff9c66a3ec
2023-01-02 17:32:59     Stack Trace:
2023-01-02 17:32:59                  file://package5/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x0000000000209902
2023-01-02 17:32:59                  file://package5/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x0000000000207E7A
2023-01-02 17:32:59                  file://package5/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x000000000026A554
2023-01-02 17:32:59                  file://package5/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x000000000026A3EC
2023-01-02 17:32:59                  file://package5/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x0000000000268D28
2023-01-02 17:32:59                  file://package5/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x0000000000201F5E
2023-01-02 17:32:59                  file://package5/windows/system32/sqlpal.dll+0x000000000039F6D8
2023-01-02 17:32:59                  file:///windows/system32/AppLoader.exe+0x0000000000002ED7
2023-01-02 17:32:59                  file:///windows/system32/AppLoader.exe+0x000000000000301D
2023-01-02 17:32:59                  file:///windows/system32/AppLoader.exe+0x000000000000303D
2023-01-02 17:32:59                  file:///windows/system32/AppLoader.exe+0x000000000000A378
2023-01-02 17:32:59                  file:///Windows/SYSTEM32/KERNEL32.DLL+0x0000000000017DF4
2023-01-02 17:32:59                  file:///windows/system32/ntdll.dll+0x000000000005B7C1
2023-01-02 17:32:59         Process: 9 - sqlservr
2023-01-02 17:32:59          Thread: 84 (application thread 0x128)
2023-01-02 17:32:59     Instance Id: 380bb4ed-2d23-4baa-8762-3d22ee32eb0d
2023-01-02 17:32:59        Crash Id: 10065506-dab0-4d16-849d-e327ed0a3da5
2023-01-02 17:32:59     Build stamp: d81e9b6de06534e649bd57dd609aa3050f5e380f361b7f8a80a80eeb71e7422c
2023-01-02 17:32:59    Distribution: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
2023-01-02 17:32:59      Processors: 20
2023-01-02 17:32:59    Total Memory: 29440778240 bytes
2023-01-02 17:32:59       Timestamp: Mon Jan  2 10:32:59 2023
2023-01-02 17:32:59 Capturing a dump of 9
2023-01-02 17:33:07 Executing: /opt/mssql/bin/handle-crash.sh with parameters
2023-01-02 17:33:07      handle-crash.sh
2023-01-02 17:33:07      /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
2023-01-02 17:33:07      9
2023-01-02 17:33:07      /opt/mssql/bin
2023-01-02 17:33:07      /var/opt/mssql/log/
2023-01-02 17:33:07      
2023-01-02 17:33:07      380bb4ed-2d23-4baa-8762-3d22ee32eb0d
2023-01-02 17:33:07      10065506-dab0-4d16-849d-e327ed0a3da5
2023-01-02 17:33:07      
2023-01-02 17:33:07      /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.1_2_2023_10_32_59.9
2023-01-02 17:33:07 Successfully captured dump: /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.1_2_2023_10_32_59.9
2023-01-02 17:33:07 
2023-01-02 17:33:08 Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
2023-01-02 17:33:08 Capturing core dump and information to /var/opt/mssql/log...
2023-01-02 17:33:08 /bin/cat: /proc/9/maps: Permission denied
2023-01-02 17:33:09 /bin/cat: /proc/9/environ: Permission denied
2023-01-02 17:33:09 /usr/bin/find: '/proc/9/map_files': Permission denied
2023-01-02 17:33:09 /usr/bin/find: '/proc/9/map_files': Permission denied
2023-01-02 17:33:09 /usr/bin/find: '/proc/9/map_files': Permission denied
2023-01-02 17:33:09 /usr/bin/find: '/proc/9/map_files': Permission denied
2023-01-02 17:33:10 dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted
2023-01-02 17:33:10 /usr/bin/timeout: failed to run command '/bin/journalctl': No such file or directory
2023-01-02 17:33:10 /usr/bin/timeout: failed to run command '/bin/journalctl': No such file or directory
2023-01-02 17:33:10 Mon Jan  2 10:33:10 UTC 2023 Capturing program information
2023-01-02 17:33:10 Dump already generated: /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.1_2_2023_10_32_59.9, moving to /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.9.temp/core.sqlservr.9.gdmp
2023-01-02 17:33:10 Moving logs to /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.9.temp/log/paldumper-debug.log
2023-01-02 17:33:10 Mon Jan  2 10:33:10 UTC 2023 Capturing program binaries
2023-01-02 17:33:12 Mon Jan  2 10:33:12 UTC 2023 Not compressing the dump files, moving instead to: /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.01_02_2023_10_33_08.9.d
```

And here is the command I'm trying to create a container

```
docker run --name SQLServer2022Test --restart always -v D:\Docker\SQL\2022\SQLTest:/var/opt/mssql -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Aa@123456" -e "MSSQL_PID=Developer" -p 3341:1433 -d 9e28798be691
```

I'm granted full control permission for docker-users in folder `D:\Docker\SQL\2022\SQLTest` but not effectively.

In my older server (run Windows Server 2019 datacenter and run docker desktop with Hyper-v), it runs very well!

My new server run Windows Server 2022 datacenter and runs docker desktop base WSL2.

Is there any solution to my problem?

Thank you for reading!

Comment: What does the `Dockerfile` that built your `9e28798be691` image look like?

Comment: This is SQL Server image of Microsoft (`mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest`). I pull it befor create so I use id of image